# How to Execute R Machine Learning Model using Python REST API?

Tags: python, r, rest, api, rpy2

I need some help in **R Machine Learning model execution by a Python REST API**.
I have 2 executable ML model, developed in R Language by my colleague.

Now I need to deploy those models as a REST API, as we need to pass some input parameter and take output from those Models as a return statement.
I found, we can do this with Python, using **RPY2 or Plumber Libraries**. So I tried to implement Flask REST API for **R model deployment**, but not getting the exact reference from google for my challenges and for learning. I am new in R-Language, just in last 2 weeks, I have explored some basis of R.

Can someone please share me some reference to my query or any other approach or code reference to **implement PYTHON REST API to execute R model** by passing some input field.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Python based REST framework like Flask(Django or Pyramid will also do) to do this. You need to understand how to write a REST API by going through their respective docs. You can basically hide the R model behind a REST Resource. This resource will be responsible in receiving the inputs for the model. Using the RPY library you can invoke the model by passing required parameters and return a response to the API client.

Comment: thanks for above info.
I know about Python Flask RESTAPI, have created api to deploy or call python ML model.
but how to hide R model behind REST Resource or deal with input/output parameter of R model, in that I don't have any knowledge, just checking those things on Google as well, but hard luck so far.

Comment: This could help - https://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-python-and-r-part-ii-executing-r-from-python-and-vice-versa/